# What to do about ambigious 'ucm' tag

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag [ucm](/questions/tagged/ucm) is currently used both for Oracle's "Universal Content Management" and ClearCase "Unified Change Management". The tag wiki currently refers to Oracle's product. There also exists a [oracle-ucm](/questions/tagged/oracle-ucm) tag while I found no other tag specific to ClearCase.

To resolve this I think the questions should get retagged as either [oracle-ucm](/questions/tagged/oracle-ucm) or [clearcase-ucm](/questions/tagged/clearcase-ucm) while the original [ucm](/questions/tagged/ucm) tag should be abandoned.

Comment: There's only ~40 questions with that tagged, manual retagging should work just fine. I'll do a few.

Comment: @Mat: That solves the current situation, not the actual problem.

Comment: @Aberrant: once questions are correctly retagged, the ucm tag will be auto-deleted. I see no need for a tag blacklisting here.

Comment: @Mat: Ah, you mean manually applying this suggested solution in stead of a moderator, then? My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ucm](/questions/tagged/ucm) is now defunct. All questions that had it were retagged with the appropriate Oracle or ClearCase alternative.